# IPO data source (NYSE / NASDAQ)

Tags: data, nasdaq, nyse

I am trying to get data for results of IPOs that took place on NYSE and NASDAQ in 2015-2020. My minimal need is:

1. Date of IPO completion
2. Company name or ticker (better yet, both)
3. Total US$ amount raised in IPO
4. Total number of shares sold in IPO
5. Optional: list of sellers who sold their shares in or along with IPO (such as venture investors of a startup going public) with amounts.

Can this data be obtained without subscribing for paid databases, and if yes, how exactly? Also, if this data is reported to SEC, what form is filed for IPO results, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Date of IPO completion
>
> Company name or ticker (better yet, both)
>
> Total US$ amount raised in IPO
>
> Total number of shares sold in IPO

[Renaissance Capital](https://www.renaissancecapital.com/IPO-Center/Pricings) has this data. They do have an option to sign up for a free 1-week trial.  I don't know what the free trial gives you compared to being a member as I have had a membership for years.

> Optional: list of sellers who sold their shares in or along with IPO (such as venture investors of a startup going public) with amounts.

You may be able to find this information in the company's S-1 filing.

There is not a filing that gives the 'results' of an IPO with the SEC.  Between the data you can get from Renaissance and data from S-1's that you can get from the SEC's EDGAR system, you should be able to find all the data you are asking for.